# Marketplace Partner Error in Opencart

Tags: model, load, opencart, marketplace

When I click in marketplace > partner, an error will be shown:

> Notice: Error: Could not load model
>   /home/payangmy/public_html/payang/admin/model/sale/customer_group.php!
>   in
>   /home/payangmy/public_html/payang/system/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php
>   on line 63

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you installed any `ocmod` extension? Try to clear modification cache first and then check it again.

Answer (score -1):

in opencart\admin\controller\customerpartner\partner.php

replace the following lines:

```
$this->load->model('sale/customer_group');

$this->data['customer_groups'] = $this->model_sale_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();
```

BY

```
$this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

$this->data['customer_groups'] = $this->model_customer_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();
```

Comment: oops, forgot one slash
opencart\admin\controller\customerpartner\partner.php

Comment: Hi we are the developer of opencart marketplace https://store.webkul.com/OpenCart-MarketPlace.html , still have any issues please raise a support ticket at https://webkul.com/ticket . Thanks